# which design pattern to use for a draw application

Tags: c#, .net, oop, design-patterns

I'm programming an add-in for autocad, but I'm stuck with a design problem. I think it can be solved by a design pattern.

I'm trying to draw a table, the table have 2 parts a frame and a top/surface. so I have these 3 classes:

- **Draw** : this class validate the user input and ask for an insertion point, create the frame and surface, and insert the new created instances into the autocad DB.
- **Frame**: calculate the frame based on length and depth.
- **Surface**: calculate the surface based on length and depth.

My problem is that if the length value given by the user is larger than max, than I have to produce 2 or more surfaces. the surface class also have to know which surface is the first and last. and the **Draw** class should also know where the first one ends to place the second surface.

What I have done now is I put the a method called calcNumberOfSurface(int len) into the Draw class and within this method I iterate  through the number of surfaces to create each time a new instate of the class Surface. this solution have two problems also, the Surface class don't know if it the first or last. and can't define the end position of the first Surface. I have to implement this into the Draw class.

Is there any best practices or a design pattern to use that solve this problem?

Comment: In my experience if you go into a project planning to use a design pattern you will over complicate it and end up spending way more time on it. Usually I will refactor into a design pattern once I see a place where it can be used efficiently. Many times design patterns will throw in a lot of stuff you don't necessarily need which is why I take that approach. So I wait until a light bulb clicks "hey this pattern would fit really well" to start using them otherwise things end up more complicated than they need to be. Anyways, that's just my preference I'm sure others will probably disagree.

Comment: "My problem is that if the length value given by the user is larger than max" - what is max? I don't get why you have to create multiple surfaces.

Comment: @preston maybe you are right, but I don't have enough experience with DP to identify if I need one and which one. My idea is to ask it here then someone maybe can recognizes the DP.

Comment: @raymond Max is the maximal length which a surface is allowed to be in a single piece. so if a user provide a length that is larger than MAX; then the program should dived the total length into two or more surfaces, each surface is than not larger than the max.

Comment: I agree with the others. You don't necessarily need design patterns for your solution, just sound OO design principles.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Preston. Before you get to Design Patterns here I think you will have to first think about all the classes that are required and what members each class will have. For your example:

- Isn't end position a member of Surface class?
- Another class maybe which denotes `List<Surface>` (list of surfaces). This class will contain first and last Surfaces.

Comment: @user1890239 This is good advice. Draw class does not need to know details about Surface. In fact, Surface can be design to be able to draw itself (derive from a IDrawable class/inherit from AbstractDrawObject and implement a Draw method). Same goes for frame.